# is possible to add more than one '?' in a url?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i need to rewrite url

my Actual URL

> http://www.domain.com/page.php?catName/ArticleName....?/&ca=7&prod=44&artId=446

i need to rewrite like this

> http://www.domain.com/catID-catName/proID-prodName/artID-ArticleName....?/page.html

Comment: "please give me a solution"  ... you misunderstand what SO is for. Please read the FAQ.  We're here to help you when you get stuck, and not as a brain substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. By the way, your modified URL only has one '?'.
From the [RFC][1] specifying the syntax of URIs and URLs, the `query` is the part of the URL that follows the `http://www.example.com/path` or `http://www.example.com` (the path is optional) component. Note that the "?" character must be the first character of the query section of the URL.

The crucial sentence in the section 3.4 of the RFC is

> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data within the query component.

Here is the pertinent section of the RFC governing URI syntax.

```
3.4 Query

The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
   data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
   resource within the scope of the URI's scheme and naming authority
   (if any).  The query component is indicated by the first question
   mark ("?") character and terminated by a number sign ("#") character
   or by the end of the URI.

      query       = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )

   The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data
   within the query component. Beware that some older, erroneous
   implementations may not handle such data correctly when it is used as
   the base URI for relative references (Section 5.1), apparently
   because they fail to distinguish query data from path data when
   looking for hierarchical separators.  However, as query components
   are often used to carry identifying information in the form of
   "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to
   another URI, it is sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-
   encoding those characters.


  [1]: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3
```